# Can not decode the binary output

Tags: python, decode

I am trying to read data from my mongodb using python.
In my mongodb there is an address `address:Binary('mA8FwsS3jBXWA/TJU0pdq9q0Hbpoz269', 0)`
I am trying to decode the address to utf-8 `.decode('utf-8')`

```
data['account']['address'].decode('utf-8')
```

but getting error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

How to decode it in a right way? Or maybe I just need to extract the data in another way?

This is not a decoded output:

```
b'\x98\x0f\x05\xc2\xc4\xb7\x8c\x15\xd6\x03\xf4\xc9SJ]\xab\xda\xb4\x1d\xbah\xcfn\xbd'
```

Comment: you can't decode as UTF-8 if it's not valid UTF-8 data in the first place.

Comment: Apply str to it directly?

Comment: This is definitely not an UTF8-encoded string. Do you know how this value was produced?

Comment: @KlausGütter This is blockchain address.

Comment: @hd1 no, it doesn't work

Comment: Then probably "mA8FwsS3jBXWA/TJU0pdq9q0Hbpoz269" *is* the address, nothing to decode.

Comment: @KlausGütter yes, this is an address and I need to extract it, but when I'm trying to extract it I am getting such output `b'\x98\x0f\x05\xc2\xc4\xb7\x8c\x15\xd6\x03\xf4\xc9SJ]\xab\xda\xb4\x1d\xbah\xcfn\xbd'`
because in mongo it looks like this `address:Binary('mA8FwsS3jBXWA/TJU0pdq9q0Hbpoz269', 0)`

Comment: @KlausGütter There *always* is something to decode when you want to go from bytes to string. It's just not UTF-8 in this case.

Comment: @KlausGütter if it's not a utf then what it can be?

Comment: Well, technically the address is the binary string you see. Usually it is repesented as Base64 or Base58 in the UI. It would help if you write down what the expected result is.